# how to make combobox entry unselectable

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combobox with a few entries like this:

```
-- Europe --
Germany
France
Spain
[...]

-- North America --
Canada
[...]
```

Now I want to make the continent-entries unselectable(or disabled), so users can't choose them. To achieve this, I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Item(0).properties("disabled", True)
```

Are there other ways to make entries unselectable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: All the list items are static.?

Comment: yes, they are static. I added them manually to the items-property of the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using below code set the `DrawMode` property of combobox1 to `OwnerDrawFixed`. Use `DrawItem` event of combobox.

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
        
Public Class Form1
    Dim DisabledList As New List(Of String)
        
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DisabledList.Add("Asia")
    DisabledList.Add("Europe")
End Sub
        
Private Sub ComboBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DrawItem
    Dim ItemFont1 As New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim ItemFont2 As New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim CurrentItem As String = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index)
    
    Using w As New SolidBrush(Color.White)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(w, e.Bounds)
    End Using    
                
    If DisabledList.Contains(CurrentItem) Then
        Using b As New SolidBrush(Color.Gray)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(CurrentItem, ItemFont2, b, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
        End Using
    Else
        e.Graphics.DrawString(CurrentItem, ItemFont1, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
    End If
End Sub
    'this event below is to handle if the user select the disabled option then option 'below it is selected. This below code only handle for the disabled item at 'index 0. you can add other index too.
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    
    Dim selectedIndex As Integer = comboBox.SelectedIndex
    If selectedIndex = 0 Then
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

If any confusion let me know.

Comment: Is it possible to display the box as a combobox with DropDownStyle=DropDownList or to change it's style to grey? Because if not, I now have a white combobox(this one) and 2 grey.

Comment: can you make your question more clear please? you mean you want to change color to grey?

Comment: I made a screenshot of it: http://i.imgur.com/mUY6bBs.png The left combobox was drawn by the code above, but the color doesn't match the 'normal' comboboxes

Comment: try changing the property backcolor to ScrollBar or as of other two combo box.